# How do I filter values according to logged in user in Django forms?

Tags: python, django, forms, view, model

I have Rank, UserProfile and Company models. These classes are connected with foreign keys. A user with Rank "Lead" can create new users from his dashboard. I want to filter Rank models according to UserProfile's company. In the sign up form there will be dropdown list to choose Rank for new user. There should only be ranks that belong to UserProfile's company. These are my models:

```
class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
    comp_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    comp_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comp_name

class Rank(models.Model):
    rank_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, unique=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rank_name


class UserProfile(AbstractUser):

    company = models.ForeignKey(CompanyProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, unique=False)
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4(), editable=False, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=500, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    rank = models.ForeignKey(Rank, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, unique=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True, null= True, default='profile.png')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

This is my form:

```
class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):


    password1 = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
    password2 = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
    

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
             'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2','rank', 'image')
```

And this is views.py:

```
@user_passes_test(is_lead)
@login_required
def signup(request):
    form_class = SignUpForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
  
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() :

            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.is_active = False
            if form.cleaned_data['password1'] != "":
                user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
                user.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = form_class()

    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to override `rank` in your `SignUpForm`.

Something along the lines of:

```
choices = [(rank.id, rank.name) for rank in Rank.objects.filter(company=...)]

rank = models.CharField(
    max_length=200,
    choices=choices,
)
```

I assume you're passing the company into the form somehow so you'll need to adjust the `filter` to filter for the company you're creating the profile for.

Comment: How can I get current user's company in the form dynamically.

Comment: It very much depends. I guess you want to restrict the Lead's to creating only users for their own company? If that's the case then you should get the company from the current logged in user (`request.user` and then retrieve their profile) and then pre-populate the `SignUpForm` with that company. Best to override the constructor of the `SignUpForm` then to populate the choices with what I posted as an answer and setting the company which was passed to `__init__`.